# Truncated incorrect INTEGER value casting not working MYSQL

Tags: mysql, casting, case, typeconverter, truncated

**I'm getting the  Truncated incorrect INTEGER value error in MYSQL, when I execute the code below. I know the logic doesn't make much sense and that will change and I am more concert about the error. I have tried casting the whole case statement but I still get the same error message.**

**Here is the original statement**

select
( count(case when v.SalesDate = v.SalesDate then v.Surname end)                     ) as x
from finaljoinalldata v
group by date(v.SalesDate)
order by date(v.SalesDate);

**I have tried also**

select
( count(CAST(case when v.SalesDate = v.SalesDate then v.Surname end) AS SIGNED)                     ) as x
from finaljoinalldata v
group by date(v.SalesDate)
order by date(v.SalesDate);

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What are the data types of the columns and can you give some example data that generates the error?

Comment: yes, the SalesDate is just a Date and the Surname is a String

Comment: I removed the group by clause it still wont work  select 
( count(case when v.SalesDate = v.SalesDate then v.Surname end)                       ) as x   
from finaljoinalldata v

Answer (score 0):

Your statement doesn't make sense.  Why do you have the `case` condition anyway?  It is redundant -- unless you are specifically checking for `NULL` values.

This should work:

```
select count(v.Surname) as x
from finaljoinalldata v
group by date(v.SalesDate)
order by date(v.SalesDate);
```

I am suspicious when I see a `group by` and the `group by` columns are not in the `select`.

Comment: The logic is more than just that, it will have a second sub-select and a join. I am not concern about the logic because on the full query I get still the same error and I have narrow it down to the statement      ( count(case when v.SalesDate = v.SalesDate then v.Surname end) ) as x , the case statement by itself runs fine but as soon as add the count to it it throws the error. Let me know it that makes sense.

Comment: I removed the group by clause it still wont work  select 
( count(case when v.SalesDate = v.SalesDate then v.Surname end)                       ) as x   
from finaljoinalldata v

Comment: In case you want to see the whole query I am trying to run is the following:   select date(v.SalesDate),
       count(case when v.SalesDate = vv.minva then v.Surname end) as num_new_users,
       (count(distinct v.Surname) - count(case when v.SalesDate = vv.minva then v.Surname end)
       ) as num_repeat_users
from finaljoinalldata v join
     (select t.Surname, min(SalesDate) as minva
      from finaljoinalldata t
      group by Surname
     ) vv
     on v.Surname = vv.Surname
group by date(v.SalesDate)
order by date(v.SalesDate);

Comment: @driveinmotors . . . These problems don't make sense.  What happens if you replace the `count()` with `sum(case when . . . then 1 else 0 end)`.